# Assign values from one array into another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I have the following structure of the state:

```
this.state = {
    data: {
        tags: []
    },
    items: [],
    input: ''
 };
```

When I submit the data, I am trying to assign the tags array with the items array data.

```
var newData = this.state.items.slice(); //copy array
this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    data: { ...this.state.data, tags: newData }
});
```

The `newData` has all variables inside, but `tags` is always empty.
How can I assign exactly the same values into the tags array?

Here is my console log:

```
console.log(this.state.data.tags, this.state.items);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idykk.png)

**UPDATE:**

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
     this.setState({ errors });
     if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
       this.setState({ loading: true });
       this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: {
             ...prevState.data,
             tags: prevState.items
           }
       }));
       console.log(this.state.data.tags, this.state.items);
       this.props
         .submit(this.state.data)
         .catch(err =>
            this.setState({ errors: err.response.data.errors, loading: false })
          );
       }
   };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set state, you don't spread the current state into the object you're passing. `setState` takes in an object as it's first argument and *only* updates the keys in that object. So, for example if we had:

```
this.state = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
```

Using this:

```
this.setState({
  b: 3
});
```

Will only update `b`. `a` will not be affected. Also, note that `setState` is asynchronous - and it's not guaranteed safe to reference state inside `setState`. Thus, React provides you with a callback to access the previous state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: { 
    ...prevState.data, 
    tags: prevState.items
  } 
}));
```

This will only update the `data` object in state, and only the `tag` property, with the previous state's `items` array.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, after using this method, array of tags is still empty

Comment: @Julia are you sure `items` is not empty?

Comment: yes, also I updated my post to show you my console log. I just found the strange problem that the array inside this.state.data is harder to change comparing with this.state . could be some problem with that?

Comment: you mean I am setting it in the wrong place? I will update my answer in a few seconds

Comment: @Julia With your code, my answer should work. There's no way `this.state.items` changes between those two calls

Comment: I just found that there are specific places where I should put this setState. And the place I was doing - seems to be wrong. now I reallocate that and it is working. thank you!